# Can't I get to Postgres with plain psql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4

I always have to give the command like `sudo -u postgres psql` in order to login into Postgres console. What do I have to in order to login into postgres like `sudo psql` or `psql`

The environment I am working on is Ubuntu Linux 12.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `which psql`? (Type that at a terminal prompt.)  Do you have both 8.4 and 9.2 installed?

Comment: /usr/bin/psql I have only 8.4 installed.

Comment: You need to be more detailed what exactly you are trying to achieve, and what exactly the problem is. Which database user do you want to login with? What is the OS user you use to start `psql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that after the installation, only the `postgres` user is able to do anything with the database server. The installer can't assume that we'd want to open access to anyone else.

To give yourself access as a casual user, assuming as an example that your login name is `joe` (your normal, non-priviledged user), you just need to create a corresponding user and database:

Inside psql as the postgres administrator (with `sudo -u postgres psql`), issue:

```
 CREATE USER joe;
 CREATE DATABASE joe OWNER joe;
```

After that, when issuing `psql` at the shell prompt, it will connect by default to your own database with your username. You no longer have to sudo to `postgres` until you need to issue other administrator commands.

Answer (score 0):

Would

> psql -U psql

work for you?

EDIT:

I though you would mind about `sudo`.

If your problem is rather typing `-U <user>`, you could also set the environment variable `PGUSER`. This could also be done in your shell's logon script, so that it will always be set.

The other enviroment variables of interest might be `PGDATABASE`, `PGHOST`, `PGPORT`.

Comment: sorry unfortunately, it doesn't

Comment: @Antony Maybe you would like to let me know why not? I can only help if you give details.

Comment: I don't like to login as postgres. Instead I would prefer to login as logged in user.

Comment: @Antony: `psql` **defaults** to the current OS user if `-U` is not specified.

Comment: @Antony Then, please, do everyone here a favour and say what you want to do and what your problem with the given solution is and why they don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your psql is in /usr/bin/psql. You shouldn't need to use sudo unless your permissions are wrong, or unless your link is wrong. (In later versions of PostgreSQL, /usr/bin/psql is a symbolic link to the executable. I don't know whether that's true in 8.4.  On my home computer, it links to /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper.)

The full skeleton syntax for psql is

```
psql -U username -h hostname -p portnumber database_name
```

So, for example, when I connect to my scratch database (named "sandbox"), I do it like this.

```
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 sandbox
```

You would substitute

- your *database* username (which must already exist, and which isn't necessarily the same as your network/computer username),
- your hostname (but "localhost" is probably right for a local install of PostgreSQL),
- the port PostgreSQL is listening on (but 5432 is probably right; it's the default), and
- your database name.

Comment: I would like to reframe the question. Is there any way i can login into Postgres with my username just like `sudo psql` taking everything else by default. Alias is one answer though, apart from that. Can we add my username into respective groups, would that help?